# java.text.ParseException: Increment > 60 : 60

Tags: java, quartz

I was using quartz-2.1.5-direct.jar with this expression :
0 0/60 23-23 ? * MON-MON

After upgrade to quartz-2.3.2-direct.jar I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Increment > 60 : 60
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.checkIncrementRange(CronExpression.java:705)
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.checkNext(CronExpression.java:840)
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.storeExpressionVals(CronExpression.java:693)
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:487)
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:276)
```

Can you please advice how to update my expression ?

Comment: What are you trying to express with that? Every 60 minutes? Why not just say "every hour", instead?

Comment: Perhaps this error message is better? *"Expression '60' is not a valid increment value. Accepted values are 0-59"*. --- `0 0/60 23-23 ? * MON-MON` has a lot of redundancy. The expression should be just **`0 0 23 ? * MON`**, meaning *"every Monday at 11 PM"*.

Comment: yes every hour until 23 MON-MON

Comment: *"every hour until 23"* No, no, no. `23-23` means it can only be in hour 23, i.e. between 23:00:00 and 23:59:59. The `0/60` means that the minute value *within* the hour should be 0 and every 60 minutes after that, but since there are only 60 minutes *within* the hour, it would just have meant `0` if it passed validation, i.e. the minute value must be 0. The first `0` means that the second value must be 0. So, hour must be 23, minute must be 0, and second must be 0, meaning time must be 23:00:00, i.e. only once per day at exactly 11 PM. `MON-MON` then restricts it to once per week, on Mondays.

Comment: @Andreas you are right . Can you explain the exception when quartz version has been changed ?

Comment: They fixed a bug, what's to explain? See [issue #58](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/58): *org.quartz.CronExpression doesn't properly check the range when an "/interval" is specified*

Answer (score -2):

The expression '60' is not a valid increment value. Accepted values are 0-59, if you don't know what you are doing read the doc and test your expression online. You can even make your expression with these tools.

http://www.cronmaker.com/?1

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: That's not an answer. It would be a great comment though. Write it as a comment to the question (you have the 50 rep needed for that), then delete this answer to clear the negative rep it is giving you.

Comment: well it definitely pass CronExpression ce = new CronExpression(cron); on  quartz-2.1.5 ...